# How to suppress moveend event while switching the base layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, events

I have created a map that contains a two base layers (Google Street Map and Open Street Map). A `moveend` event listener is registered to listen for any map movement which would perform a function call to load in new data based on the bounds of the map view port. I realise that the function call is performed even when switching the base layer without causing any map movement. Is there a way to switch the base layer silently?

As requested, the code in brief:

```
var map;
var gmap_r = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Street Map');
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('Open Street Map');
var options = {
  layers: [gmap_r, osm, markers]
...
};
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
map.events.register('moveend', map, my_function);
//code above used for triggering a call to my_function upon a map pan or zoom event
```

The change of base layer unfortunately triggers the above as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you share your code, we can make a good point for you. addition to the `moveend` listener you can chek out [OpenLayers.Control.DragPan](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DragPan-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DragPan.panMapDone) method for your request.

```
function dragged(){
     console.info('map dragged');
};

var drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragPan({'map':map, 'panMapDone':dragged});

drag.draw();
map.addControl(drag);
drag.activate();
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I have edited my question to add in the relevant code, not sure if it this is what you want.. but I don't get what you are trying to achieve with by adding a DragPan control..

Comment: it is the same as moveend method.

Comment: Ok, you mean replace the moveend method with DragPan as a workaround?

Comment: I added another listener to listen for `changebaselayer` event and use that as a workaround. Think it solved now. Thanks for your help :)